# Выборка парсером Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, html

Не получается считать значение из атрибута 'a', у меня есть кусок кода:

```
<td class="text">
<div class="advtext">
<a class="preview" rel="/query/565656/" href="/photos/bazar/d4/3969944/medium_3969944_0.jpg" title="">
<a href="/query/565656/">Продаём Японские скутеры</a>
</div>
</td>
```

Я написал вот что:

```
foreach($html->find('.list .norm .text .advtext .preview') as $element){
    echo '1. Название: ' . $element->rel . '<br>';
}
```

то есть я защел в 'a' class="preview" и считал все, что надо, но не могу считать все, что лежит под классом 'a', тоже тег 'a', но уже без класса, не могу допетрить, как к нему прицепиться?

То есть не могу считать это: `<a href="/query/565656/">Продаём Японские скутеры</a>`

Comment: то есть достаточно указать последний ? понятно, а я думал надо всю цепочку писать что бы ему удобнее было идти по дереву.

Comment: Не совсем последний) До элемента можно добраться несколькими путями, все они будут корректны, но разумнее использовать кратчайший путь. Парсер быстрее найдет ваш элемент + он меньше связан со структурой документа, что тоже плюс.

Answer (score 2):

$element->nextSibling() - получает следующий элемент уровня.

По вашему куску кода не особо понятна структура, но если опираться на него, то вы зря используете столько классов для пути к нужному элементу. Может хватило бы селектора ".advtext a"? Так вы бы получили все ссылки внутри .advtext

UPD. У вас тег **a.preview** не закрыт. Обновите структуру, по ней непонятно, что вам надо. Внутри **.advtext** много ссылок? **a** вложен в **a.preview** или они на одном уровне?

Comment: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm

$e->next_sibling () Returns the next sibling of element, or null if not found.

Про селекторы - это из здравого смысла =) Используйте кратчайший путь.

Comment: даже с такой подсказкой я не справился, прошу помощи.

Comment: <div class="advtext">
<a class="preview" rel="/query/3969944/" href="/3969944/medium_3969944_0.jpg" title="">
<img class="advphoto" alt="Продаём Японские скутеры" src="/3969944/small_3969944_0.jpg">
</a>
<a href="/query/3969944/">Продаём Японские скутеры</a>
</div>

Comment: Раз у вас в .advtext всего две ссылки, то не нужно использовать foreach. Достаточно

    $html->find(".advtxt a", 1); // получите вторую ссылку внутри .advtxt


Возможно вам надо использовать цикл по .advtext, если их много на странице?

    $advtexts = $html->find(".list .norm .text .advtext");
    foreach($advtexts as $advtext) {
        $apreview = $advtext->find("a.preview", 0); // объект a.preview внутри текущего advtext
        $a = $advtext->find("a", 1); // ...
        echo $a->plaintext; // внутренности a, т.е. "Продаём Японские скутеры"
    }

Comment: можно узнать ваши контакты ?

Comment: эм. нет) Я же не техподдержка css-селекторов и simple_html_dom. Простите.

Comment: Спасибо, дальше пойду сам, это правильно.